# Godot's editor output window prints: Condition ' base.begins_with("local://") || base == "" ' is true. Continuing..:

Tags: godot

When I play the project I get the following output from the godot's editor output window.

Output:

```
editor/plugins/script_editor_plugin.cpp:1427 - Condition ' base.begins_with("local://") || base == "" ' is true. Continuing..:
```

So what is that supposed to tell me?
I noticed it's just a warning and the project might run anyway.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried closing out the project and opening and running again? Does it give the same warning/error? I find I have often received errors such as this after I have moved files around in the project folder (usually when I finally get around to making proper folders to separate my images, scripts, scene data, etc...). I have found that restarting the editor usually stops the warning, but in case it doesn't, I've seen much talk around the Godot community that if something is giving a warning or error, but the scene still runs anyway, there's a good chance you can just ignore it.

Comment: Hey, thanks. The warning message disappeared after relaunching the project.

Answer (score 3):

That happens when there is a scene script `.gd` file in the same folder as the script `.tscn` file and you rename the script. In that case you will get an error similar to `Another resource is loaded from path 'res://Scene_01/some_script.gd' (possible cyclic resource inclusion).` and an unnamed script will appear in the script list.

Just close the unnamed script(s) and the warning you mentioned will disappear. Or even better, move the script file to some other folder.